# How to Parse the dynamic key vale in php

Tags: php, json

how to manage dynamic key in json

```
 [
      {
        "batch_id": "132",
        "benf_id": "ANP-JAI-1190",
        "NA3": "",
        "NA4": "",
        "status": "Y",
        "NA5": "",
        "datapoint_id": "105",
        "status_update_time": "28/8/2017 ",
        "user_id": "santoshk",
        "pop_id": "40",
        "measuring": "1000ltr",
        "weight": "100gm"
      },

      {
        "batch_id": "133",
        "benf_id": "ANP-JAI-1195",
        "NA3": "",
        "NA4": "",
        "status": "Y",
        "NA5": "",
        "datapoint_id": "106",
        "status_update_time": "28/8/2017 ",
        "user_id": "santoshk",
        "pop_id": "41",
        "water": "1000ltr",
        "medicine": "100gm"
      }

    ]
```

// my php code

```
public function benf_status_update($jdata)
{
    $count=0;
    $this->load->model('m_sf_user');
    while($count < count($jdata))
    {
        $batch_id = $jdata[$count]->batch_id;
        $benf_id = $jdata[$count]->benf_id;
        $m3=$jdata[$count]->NA3;
        $m4=$jdata[$count]->NA4;
        $status = $jdata[$count]->status;
        $m5=$jdata[$count]->NA5;
        $m1=$jdata[$count]->0;
        $m2=$jdata[$count]->0;
        $datapoint_id = $jdata[$count]->datapoint_id;
        $status_update_time = $jdata[$count]->status_update_time;
        $user_id =$jdata[$count]->user_id;
        $pop_id = $jdata[$count]->pop_id;
        $benf_id = substr($benf_id,8,strlen($benf_id));
        $qry = "UPDATE pop_b_m_points a JOIN m_pop_batch b ON 
                        b.pop_id=".$pop_id."
                        and b.batch_id=".$batch_id."
                        and  a.data_p_id=b.dpoint_id
                        and a.benf_id=".$benf_id."
                        and a.m_point_id=".$datapoint_id."
                        SET a.status='".$status."',
                         a.m1='".$m1."',
                         a.m2='".$m2."',
                         a.m3='".$m3."',
                         a.m4='".$m4."',
                         a.m5='".$m5."' ,                   
                        a.update_time= (SELECT (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('".$status_update_time."', '%d/%m/%Y' ), '%Y%m%d')))";

        $this->m_sf_user->jSONservices_u($qry);
        $count++;
    }
    $x=array('json_status'=>"success");
    echo json_encode($x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
json_decode($string) to convert String into Array/Object (stdClass).
```

Example:

```
$myRawJson = '{
  "batch_id": "133",
  "benf_id": "ANP-JAI-1195",
  "NA3": "",
  "NA4": "",
  "status": "Y",
  "NA5": "",
  "datapoint_id": "106",
  "status_update_time": "28/8/2017 ",
  "user_id": "santoshk",
  "pop_id": "41",
  "water": "1000ltr",
  "medicine": "100gm"
}';

$myAssoc  = json_decode($myRawJson);
$myObject = (object)(json_decode($myRawJson));

var_dump($myAssoc['medicine']); //100gm
var_dump($myObject->medicine); //100gm
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't know for sure which columns you will get, but do want to save all. Then make an extra column 'data' in which you save the complete set of data through json_encode()

If you can make sure some fields are always there, use them in seperate columns in order to filter and order by those, but also use the data column to add the complete data set.